# How to generate a drop-down list full with hyperlink in Laravel 4?

Tags: html, laravel-4, laravel-blade

**GOAL**

Generate a drop-down list that contain a hyperlink in Laravel 4 using Blade

**INFORMATION**

- I populated the list from my database data.
- Everything work great, and it's display as a list of text.
- Now, I want to turn those texts into hyperlink using the `<a>` tag.
- I am not sure how to do that.

**QUESTION**

Am I close or at least on the right track ?

**CODE**

```
<?php $active = User::where('type','=','Distributor')->where('active','=', 1)->lists('username'); ?>
                {{ Form::select('', $active,''array('href' => 'www.google.com' ) }}
```

**Image**

[image: **Image**]

Comment: HTML selects do not support hyperlinks. Either you have to use javascript and detect the click event or add a button next to it and navigate to the url when the button is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, how will you do that exactly, but I got some suggestion. 
Rather than making a drop-down list,how about a button that will trigger a modal with a list of things that you want to list.

That the only way, that I think fit your case.

If you choose to do that, here is how to make that link

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#list"  >Active</a>
```

According to your code, here is how I suggest for the Modal box, but of course, you can modify as you wish, this is just sample structure.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="list" >
    <div class=" col-lg-4"> </div>
    <div class=" col-lg-4">

        <br><br><br><br><br>



        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" data-target="#modal-step-contents">
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-white pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">
                    x

                </button>
                <h1 class="lighter">Active</h1>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-body step-content" id="modal-step-contents">

                <td >
                    <a href="/distributors/{{$pending_distributor->id}}">{{ $pending_distributor->company_name }}</a>
                </td>



            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer wizard-actions">

                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-next" data-dismiss="modal">
                    Close

                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope this help !